# How to get the HTTP Response status in django class based views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using Django 2.2. I want to get the HTTP response status code while code is successfully rendered through CBV( Django's class-based view ). I am able to do it when I am using render() method in Function-based views. Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

My code look's like this

```
class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = <my model>
    template_name = < my template path >

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        < my code block for assigning HTML data to context >     
        return context
```

Here I am returning the context and it's successfully getting renders over the browser as HTML, but how can I get HTTP response status code in views.py ??

Comment: Follow django documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/#supporting-other-http-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can override in get() method.

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.status_code = 200
        return response
```

Comment: But when this function get called while get_conext_data is in progress or rendering my HTML data?

Comment: You might have added the class in one of url end points in urls.py. When the get request is done, it should automatically get called.